# How to prevent liberty from converting "+" to " " in URL

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

We had an issue where clients were sending "+" as part of a parameter value without percent-encoding it.  After digging in, it looks like converting "+" to " " is from HTML form encoding, but not part of the URL spec.

I found https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00005phvXb/urls-with-or-2b-in-the-path-or-query-are-incorrectly-decoded-to-space?language=en_US which sounds exactly like what we're hitting, but with Liberty 19.0.0.8 (and probably for some time), even excpicitly setting `decodeUrlPlusSign="false"` doesn't seem to help.

That is, when we call `req.getParameter(queryParameterName)` it is returning the value with a " " instead of a "+".

I'm setting it in server.xml as follows:

```
<webContainer disableXPoweredBy="true" decodeUrlPlusSign="false" />
```

What exactly is `decodeUrlPlusSign` supposed to do?  Is it working as expected?

Comment: One alternative we found was to capture the HttpServletRequest .getQueryString();   and use that queryString to rewrite the converted ' ' back to '+'.   I remain very interested in decodeUrlPlusSign's intended setting.

Comment: APAR PK23481 implies even when you opt in, it only changes the behavior of decoding + outside of the query string (path and path_info components of the URL)

Comment: @covener how did you find that?  Mind sharing a link?

Comment: This information was public in the past but it has been dropped over the years from the web due to its age, so I reproduced it here:

https://hastebin.com/alofuvuzif.coffeescript